# Html object tag for svg find width

Tags: javascript, object, svg, elm

I have

```
<object
   data="${content}"
   type="image/svg+xml"
></object>
```

Where content is a svg.

Currently I am trying to figure this on elm.

```
    object
        [ Attr.attribute "data" "${content}"
        , Attr.type_ "image/svg+xml"
        ]
        []
```

QUESTION:
how can i find the width of the svg?

I tried in elm `on "load"` but it does not fire.
Javascript or elm solution welcomed, but i prefer elm

I tried on elm

```
on "change" decodeImgLoad
```

or

```
on "load" decodeImgLoad
```

but they do not get called at all.

When I used img instead of object it worked, but I want to have the svg set up correctly on the dom and not just as image.

In elm I can not reference the svg directly, i need img or object or to convert it into elm svg.
(to convert it into elm svg is not possible, as the svg is large)

Comment: Do you need the width of the SVG inside the object element or the width of the object element?

Comment: I need the width of the svg

Answer (score 0):

First of all this needs to run from a webserver. Running it from the filesystem does not work. SVG document must have the same origin as the HTML document. If not, `document` will be `null`.

Make sure that both the HTML document AND the SVG document has been loaded before starting to request the DOM. Here you have a simple example:

#### HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        // call the object element by its id
        document.getElementById('object01').addEventListener('load', e => {
          let objectElm = e.target;
          let svgElm = objectElm.contentDocument.rootElement;
          console.log(svgElm.clientWidth, svgElm.clientHeight);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <object id="object01" data="svg.svg"></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### SVG document (svg.svg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <circle id="c1" cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="Orange" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to answer you question with JavaScript.

Q = Find width of svg that is in an object tag.

Ans = Use this js code

```js
  var svg = document.getElementById('YourSVG');
  var get = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  var width = get.width;
  var height = get.height;
```

Comment: I will try it later. The svg is on a page of Single Page Application(SPA).
So using js before it appears will not work.
Workaround is: When elm opens the page to call js and find the width to send it back to elm.

Comment: you have to wait for the onload event for this to work.

Comment: Did you try https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom#getViewportOf to get the size?

Comment: I will use javascript. I want to get the offsetWidth to use it as relative stop position on a svg. (i got numbers where to stop and depending on the width i am calculating the stop position). Thanks for your support.